# 2006 Honda Civic hybrid low idle

Tags: idle, air-intake

I changed my air intake and everything seems fine except I noticed my idle is below zero rpm now the car feels fine. Is the car not use to the normal amount of air it's getting now? It seems to be running fine but this caught my attention please help.

Comment: Can’t be below 0 rpm as it would not be running...

Comment: Hi Brian - welcome. Can you please edit your post to give us more info. For example, currently you say it is idling at below 0 rpm - which is not possible.

Comment: I changed the air intake because there was a crack. When I say the car is idle at 0rpm because the needle with clearly be below 0 but the engine feels totally fine not like it's about to turn off. I tried to relearn idle procedure but must be doing something wrong. Before I changed it the rpms at idle were normal. Anyone else know what todo

Comment: Is there a chance the computer will reset it's self after I drive a while? Also Todo the idle relearn do I need a computer to plug into my car? Or can I get it to be engage some other way

Comment: Your RPM is not 0. Your gauge in cluster has gone bad or the cluster is not receiving the required information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking that you go through your engine bay and check that you didn't forget any plugs or connectors while installing the new intake. If your car is running then RPM's SHOULD be displayed, so it seems that the cars computer is just not receiving that information due to a disconnect or maybe a blown fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trusting us with your issue! I see two possible solutions.  The first,  is that your hybrid isn't running the engine at the time. I'm assuming that this isn't the issue, but I have a policy of starting with the very simplest option possible.

So the second is that you unplugged or damaged the crankshaft position sensor, is wiring, or connector while you were working. [Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zb7rBZGQ1PM) is a video showing you where it is.  Grab the connector(not the wiring!) and gently pull back on it.  It shouldn't move. If it does,  use electronics cleaner to clean the connecter and sensor, let it dry, then reconnect it, ensuring that it clicks. If it's fine,  follow the wiring as far as you can,  looking for damage.  Finally, if it still looks fine, then disconnect the connector and verify that you have 5 volts on one of the terminals of the connector. If you do, your sensor may be bad and this is a coincidence(however unlikely).

Oh,  if you have a scanner,  skip all that and watch your rpm pid in your live data.  If it's there, then there's an issue with either your tachometer, the wiring for your instrument cluster, or your pcm.

Let me know if that helps!